# Game crashes when run outside Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, sfml

I've used C++ to create a game in VS2010, and it runs fine (if extremely laggy :( ) on debug, and runs smoothly on release mode. However, when run outside of it (even when running the exe from the project directory) it opens, draws the starting scene then freezes and  just says "has stopped responding".

What could cause this?

EDIT: In studio I occasionally get an error which stops the program, and in the call stack it only shows ntdll.dll

Comment: Perhaps you didn't place the resource files to the right place?

Comment: Rango: no, because the image displays correctly on start up. The scene is created and your character and some walls can be seen, it just freezes immediately. I'm just looking for possible causes, because at the moment I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SFML are you using? I have experienced problems with ATI video cards with SFML 1.6. Except on my computer, usually it opens the window and immediately closes it before drawing everything; so I am not sure if this could possibly be your problem. This issue is supposedly fixed in version 2.0, so if you have an ATI card and version 1.6, consider porting to 2.0 and see if this fixes your problem.